# How to prevent caching of php files?

Tags: 12.04, apache2, php

After removing varnish cache from local server I noticed strange behaviour of Apache server.
When ever you update a php file and try to open it in a browser old response is shown, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> does not refresh a page, but if you type in `service apache2 restart` all changes appear.

Can some one point what could possibly went wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have [apc.stat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.stat)  set to `0` in which case APC will always serve the cached version of PHP files without checking the file on disk for changes anymore.

You can find out with a `<?php phpinfo() ?>` on any page.

To change that setting, check the content of `/etc/php5/conf.d/apc.ini`.